# How to check if the location service is enabled or not in Appcelerator

Tags: android, gps, appcelerator

Can you please help me to check  if the location service is enabled or not in Appcelerator.
I am working with Titanium SDk 6.1.2 and Samsung S5 with Marshmellow OS. Even though the GPS is enabled/not in device, But every time it results in false.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to check for **Location Permissions** for app in Android & then you need to check if location service is enabled in device or not.

Both are different statements.

First one checks for app permission to access location & 2nd is about checking location service is on or off.

Without checking **Location Permissions** first on Android, you cannot check for location on/off state, else it will always lead to **false** status.

**First of all add this in tiapp.xml in ios -> plist -> dict**

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string>Determine Current Location</string>
```

Now here's the cross-compatible code for Android/iOS.

```
function checkLocationEnabledOrNot(_callback, _args) {
    if (Titanium.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
        _callback(_args);

    } else {
        alert("Turn on location on your device.");
    }
}


// pass _callback method you want to call after successful access to location
// you can also pass arguments as 2nd parameter to the function you want to call

function startLocationProcess(_callback, _args) {
    Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_HIGH;

    if (OS_IOS) {
        checkLocationEnabledOrNot(_callback, _args);

    } else if (OS_ANDROID) {
        if (Ti.Geolocation.hasLocationPermissions()) {
            checkLocationEnabledOrNot(_callback, _args);

        } else {
            Ti.Geolocation.requestLocationPermissions(Ti.Geolocation.AUTHORIZATION_ALWAYS, function (locationEvent) {
                if (locationEvent.success) {
                    checkLocationEnabledOrNot(_callback, _args);

                } else {
                    alert("Location permissions are required to access locations.");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Now, on a button click whatever you want to do after location check, you can simply do it like this:

```
function anotherFunction(name) {
    alert(name);
}


$.someButton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    startLocationProcess(anotherFunction, "Hello D.Ish");
});
```